# googlesheets script is not formatting my content correctly

Tags: google-apps-script

My googlesheet script is not formatting my content correctly. Can someone help me out?  Here is my script.

```
function NewIssue() {
  var spreadsheet = SpreadsheetApp.getActive();
  var cell = spreadsheet.getCurrentCell();
  var user = Session.getActiveUser().getEmail().substring(0, 2).toUpperCase();
  var oldContent = cell.getValue();
  var newContent1 = '********************ISSUE********************\n';
  var newContent2 = 'Group:\n\nDescription:\n\nExpected Results:\n\nActual Results:\n\nTest Results:\n\nTest Data:\n\n\n';
  var space = " ";

  //Keep the format of the old content and add format to newContent1
  var newStyles = [{
    start: 0,
    end: newContent1.length,
    style: SpreadsheetApp.newTextStyle().setBold(true).setForegroundColor("red").build()
  }];
  var richTextValue = cell.getRichTextValue();
  var offset = newContent1.length + newContent2.length + space.length;
  var oldContent = richTextValue.getText();
  if (oldContent.length > 0) {
    richTextValue.getRuns().forEach(function(e) {
      newStyles.push({
        start: offset + e.getStartIndex(),
        end: offset + e.getEndIndex(),
        style: e.getTextStyle()
      });
    });
  }

  var d = new Date(); 
  var richText = SpreadsheetApp.newRichTextValue().setText(user + "_" + d.dateNow() + "_" + d.timeNow() + "\n" + newContent1 + newContent2 + space + oldContent);
  newStyles.forEach(function(e) {richText.setTextStyle(e.start, e.end, e.style)});
  cell.setRichTextValue(richText.build());

  Date.prototype.timeNow = function () 
{
     return ((this.getHours() < 10)?"0":"") + ((this.getHours()>12)?(this.getHours()-12):this.getHours()) +":"+ ((this.getMinutes() < 10)?"0":"") + this.getMinutes() + ((this.getHours()>=12)?('pm'):'am');
}
// Returns the current date with formatting like: 6.16.19
Date.prototype.dateNow = function ()

{
     return (this.getMonth()+1 +"."+ this.getDate() +"."+ this.getYear().toString().substr(-2));
}   

}
```

When running the above script, I get the following:

[image1](https://i.stack.imgur.com/Py1Jz.jpg)

[image]

I want it to look like this:

[image2](https://i.stack.imgur.com/lKnql.jpg)

[image]

I want user, date, time to be all black and non bold as
AO_2.19.20_11:57pm

I want ********************ISSUE******************** to be all red and bold.

I can't figure out how to make this happen.  Any suggestions will be helpful.

Answer (score 0):

- You want to give the text styles of the red ForegroundColor and bold to only `********************ISSUE********************` of `newContent1`.
- You don't want to change the text style to `newContent2` and `user + "_" + d.dateNow() + "_" + d.timeNow() + "\n"`.
- You want to add the old value in the cell to the last value of `newContent2` and `user + "_" + d.dateNow() + "_" + d.timeNow() + "\n"` + `newContent1` + `newContent2`.

If my understanding is correct, how about this answer? Please think of this as just one of several possible answers.

#### Modification points:

- In your script, the start index and end index of `newContent1` is not correct. Because `user + "_" + d.dateNow() + "_" + d.timeNow() + "\n"` is added by `setText(user + "_" + d.dateNow() + "_" + d.timeNow() + "\n" + newContent1 + newContent2 + space + oldContent)`.

  - In this modification, it declares `user + "_" + d.dateNow() + "_" + d.timeNow() + "\n"` as `newContent0`. And the start and end indexes of each value are set.
  - When you want to give the default text style to the values except for `newContent1`, in this case, it is required to give `null` as the style.

When above points are reflected to your script, it becomes as follows.

#### Modified script:

```
function NewIssue() {
  Date.prototype.timeNow = function () {
     return ((this.getHours() < 10)?"0":"") + ((this.getHours()>12)?(this.getHours()-12):this.getHours()) +":"+ ((this.getMinutes() < 10)?"0":"") + this.getMinutes() + ((this.getHours()>=12)?('pm'):'am');
  }
  Date.prototype.dateNow = function (){
    return (this.getMonth()+1 +"."+ this.getDate() +"."+ this.getYear().toString().substr(-2));
  }

  var spreadsheet = SpreadsheetApp.getActive();
  var cell = spreadsheet.getCurrentCell();
  var user = Session.getActiveUser().getEmail().substring(0, 2).toUpperCase();
  var oldContent = cell.getValue();
  var d = new Date();
  var newContent0 = user + "_" + d.dateNow() + "_" + d.timeNow() + "\n";  // Added
  var newContent1 = '********************ISSUE********************\n';
  var newContent2 = 'Group:\n\nDescription:\n\nExpected Results:\n\nActual Results:\n\nTest Results:\n\nTest Data:\n\n\n';
  var space = " ";
  var content0Len = newContent0.length;  // Added
  var content1Len = newContent1.length;  // Added
  var content2Len = newContent2.length;  // Added
  var newStyles = [  // Modified
    {start: 0, end: content0Len, style: null},
    {start: content0Len, end: content0Len + content1Len, style: SpreadsheetApp.newTextStyle().setBold(true).setForegroundColor("red").build()},
    {start: content0Len + content1Len, end: content0Len + content1Len + content2Len, style: null}
  ];
  var richTextValue = cell.getRichTextValue();
  var offset = newContent0.length + newContent1.length + newContent2.length + space.length;
  var oldContent = richTextValue.getText();
  if (oldContent.length > 0) {
    richTextValue.getRuns().forEach(function(e) {
      newStyles.push({
        start: offset + e.getStartIndex(),
        end: offset + e.getEndIndex(),
        style: e.getTextStyle()
      });
    });
  }
  var richText = SpreadsheetApp.newRichTextValue().setText(newContent0 + newContent1 + newContent2 + space + oldContent);  // Modified
  newStyles.forEach(function(e) {richText.setTextStyle(e.start, e.end, e.style)});
  cell.setRichTextValue(richText.build());
}
```

#### Note:

- In your sample output image, it seems that `user + "_" + d.dateNow() + "_" + d.timeNow()` has 2 line breaks. If it's so, please modify as follows.

  - From

    ```
    var newContent0 = user + "_" + d.dateNow() + "_" + d.timeNow() + "\n";
    ```
  - To

    ```
    var newContent0 = user + "_" + d.dateNow() + "_" + d.timeNow() + "\n\n";
    ```

#### Reference:

- [Class RichTextValueBuilder](https://developers.google.com/apps-script/reference/spreadsheet/rich-text-value-builder)

If I misunderstood your question and this was not the direction you want, I apologize.